# SPARC assembly, How a C pointer to struct is accessed

Tags: c, pointers, assembly, struct, sparc

I have a small piece of SPARC assembly code that I'm trying to understand.

```
 .section ".text"
 .global tt_0x09
tt_0x09:
 /* Find AHBSTAT */
 set ahbstat, %l3
 ld [%l3], %l3
 /* Get failing address from AHBSTAT faddr. */
 ld [%l3 + 4], %l4

 set 0xDEADBEEF, %l5
 st %l5, [%l4]

 /*st %g0, [%l3]*/
 /* Re-execute trapped instruction. */
 jmp %l1
 rett %l2
```

where `ahbstat` is defined in a C file

```
#define AHBSTAT_REGS 0x80000f00
struct ahbstat_regs { unsigned int status, faddr; };
...
volatile struct ahbstat_regs *ahbstat = (void *) AHBSTAT_REGS;
```

For the sake of completeness, the assembly snippet I showed above is the code of a trap which is mapped using a particular library function:

`extern void tt_0x09(void);
static const int TT_DATA_ACCESS_EXCEPTION = 0x09;
...
bcc_set_trap(TT_DATA_ACCESS_EXCEPTION, tt_0x09);`

The point which I do not understand is how the struct is accessed in the assembly code. In fact, if `l3`contains the address of the struct, then using `ld [%l3], %l3` I'm loading a word from the memory to `l3` it self, So I'm copy the value of the `unsigned int status` of the struct into `l3`.

Another problem is in the consecutive lines: It set `l5` to `0xDEADBEEF` and then store `l5` in the memory location pointed to `l4`. But `l4` has been loaded with the value at memory location `[%l3+4]` which is a non-sense as far as I understand because `l3` contains the value of  `unsigned int status` of the struct.

The program should write `0xdeadbeef` in the memory location pointed by the failing address, which is the address contained in `faddr` of the struct.

I'm wrong somewhere, but I think I'm clear with the  `load` instruction:
`ld [addr], rd` -> Load a word from addr into rd.

So I do not think it's clear to me how a C struct pointer is "translated" in assembly.

Thanks in advance for your help, excuse me if something I wrote is not clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have almost understood everything correctly except for what `ahbstat` is.

In the C code, you can see the declaration -

```
volatile struct ahbstat_regs *ahbstat = (void *) AHBSTAT_REGS;
```

which means `ahbstat` is a pointer to the struct. The label `ahbstat` in assembly thus becomes the address of this pointer. Which makes `%l3`, the address of the address of the struct.

I think with this correction, you can figure out the rest.

Comment: I understood that `ahbstat` was a pointer to the struct. I did not know instead how the label `ahbstat` would become in assembly. With your correction I have a clear vision of the total snippet. Thank you Ajay

Comment: @Andak: C global / static variable names always become asm label names that refer to the static storage where the variable's value is stored.